# Redirect to Login wrong when running .NET Core 3.1 on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a .NET core 3.1 application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

My pipeline is `HTTPS -> ALB -> HTTP -> Instance`.

The problem I am facing is that when I require authentication, the redirect `Location:` header is **http** and **absolute** and the browser redirects incorrectly.

To resolve this, I need to either:

- Make the `Location:` header relative, or
- Get the `Location:` header to be https.

I am using `app.UseForwardedHeaders()` in my `Startup.cs` file as per [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1), to try to make it https, but it still is http.

What needs to be done to get ASP.NET core Identity to work on Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the configuration of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides` module.

By default, it was restricting `KnownNetworks` to `127.0.0.1` and `KnownProxies` to `::1`. So when the request came from my ALB, it did not move the scheme from `X-Forwarded-For` to `this.Request.Scheme`.

The issue is resolved when I clear the networks and proxies during configuration, like this:

```cs
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear(); // These are key
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });
```

**New Unknown:**

Q: Is it safe to do this?

A: In my case, my EC2 instance is in a private subnet and my security group is restricting traffic to that from my ALB, so I feel pretty safe. But more research is required.